# How to manipulate ReDim preserve multidimensional array ID's?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an issue that, multi dimensional array which is trying to put the ID's for group member combinations from calendar hierarchy (Year -> super_Season -> Quarter -> month -> week). problem is one of the Week's ID number to be changed when it comes to the particular week. Say for example as per the screenshot if this week comes the ID/index should get increased by 1

#### Entry which needs to change the ID

[image: entry which need to change the ID]

The code which i have to modify for this issue is as below

```
Public Function writeStructure(intdimension As Integer) As Boolean
Dim objGroup As Variant
Dim objMember As Variant
Dim strError As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
    
    On Error GoTo ErrorRoutine
    
    writeStructure = False

    'write structure
        strError = "writing structure to " & readIniFileString("Dimensions", "Name" & intdimension, strControlFileIni)
        With Worksheets(readIniFileString("Dimensions", "Name" & intdimension, strControlFileIni))
            .Cells.Clear
            i = 1
            For Each objGroup In objGroups.Items
                .Cells(i, 1).Value = objGroup.Number
                .Cells(i, 2).Value = objGroup.Name
                i = i + 1
            Next

            i = 1
            For Each objMember In objMembers.Items
                .Cells(i, 3).Value = objMember.Number
                .Cells(i, 4).Value = objMember.Name
                .Cells(i, 5).Value = objMember.Description
                .Cells(i, 6).Value = objMember.Group
                .Cells(i, 7).Value = objMember.groupName
                For j = 1 To objMember.countOfParents
                    .Cells(i, 7 + j).Value = objMember.Parent(j) ' ID values are assigning
                Next j
                i = i + 1
            Next
        End With
```

Comment: What's the problem *exactly* with your current code?

Comment: problem is as this is dynamic array how to change ID's value to some other value when specified week comes?

Comment: I don't see any arrays here

Comment: .Cells(i, 7 + j).Value = objMember.Parent(j) for this line of code it will traverse to this function                                                                      Public Function Parent(intParent As Integer) As Integer
    'get parent
        Parent = intParents(intParent)
End Function                                                                                                   In this ReDim intParents(0) as integer

Comment: This seems to be a question related to the implementation of your custom class(es) - it would be more helpful to post the code for the class in question.